# Unexpected Pointer behavior

Tags: c++

I am confused with what exactly goes wrong in the following demo code. I expected that the next would keep pointing to the next element in the chain until reached end. `However, I get EXE_BAD_ADDESS` error. I guess I am missing something in the recursive pointer assignment.

```
template <class T>
struct Node {
    Node *left, *right, *parent;
    int height;
    T value;

    // constructor
    Node(T val)
    : value(val){
        height = 0;
        left = right = NULL;
    }
};


template <class T>
void assignToNext(Node<T> *n, Node<T> *next){

    // base case
    if (n == NULL)
        return;

    // else assign to this node and check for next
    next = n;

    assignToNext(n->left, next);
}
```

And then in the main:

```
Node<int> a(1);
a.left = new Node<int>(2);
a.left->left = new Node<int>(3);
a.left->left->left = new Node<int>(4);
a.left->left->left->left = new Node<int>(5);

Node<int> *last = NULL;

assignToNext(&a, last);

std::cout << last->value << std::endl;   // I get EXE_BAD_ADDRESS error
```

Thanks in advance,
Nikhil

Comment: `last` is being passed **by value**...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Thanks :). I did suspect that. But I am still finding it tough to digest. The function `assignToNext` does intake a pointer. I thought it would do pass-by-referencing thing. Am I missing something here?

Comment: But the pointer **itself** is passed by value.  The function operates on a **copy** of the pointer.

Comment: `n` and `next` are local variables within the function `assignToNext`. They disappear forever when `assignToNext` returns, and so the assignment has no lasting effect. The assigned value of `next` is used in making the recursive call, so the assignment changes the behavior of that call. However, you can rewrite the call as `assignToNext(n->left, n)` and remove the assignment to `next`. (The compiler will likely do something like that when optimizing.) Note that when you do that, the parameter `next` has no use in your function. This is in fact the case; you've overwritten the incoming value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`void assignToNext(Node<T> *n, Node<T> *next){`

-->

`void assignToNext(Node<T> *n, Node<T> *&next){` // note the &

Otherwise the original pointer isn't updated and stays NULL.

Comment: That's the thing :).... strange I never encountered this problem before :-o.. Thanks!

Comment: @NikhilJJoshi Please understand it before just doing it. Do you know what the `&` that @egur added means? From your code, it looks like you might not know. It is *not* the address-of operator.

Comment: @sftrabbit,  I do understand it. just missed it before.

Comment: @NikhilJJoshi What does it mean then? :)

Comment: it's just a pointer to a pointer. The same as to "change the original object one passes the pointer", just one more level up, now we change the original pointer by referring it by its address.

Answer (score 2):

```
assignToNext(&a, last);
```

This code can't modify local variable `Node<int> *last`'s value. You just passed `NULL` to parameter `Node<T> *next`. So `last`'s value is still `NULL` and you got error. If you want modify pointer's value, use double pointer.

Like,

```
void assignToNext(Node<T> *n, Node<T> **next);
assignToNext(&a, &last);
```